# Beyond least squares: how to choose a predictive model or algorithm? (reference request)

Tags: predictive-models, references, prediction

There are [dozens](https://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html) of algorithms one can use to build a predictive model.

What books or studies exist that can help one determine which algorithm to use? *Elements of Statistical Learning* spends a lot of time talking about each model it covers (and it covers a lot of them), but not much time comparing use cases and performance.

Comment: Conventionally, one tests several alternatives and compare out-of-sample performance metrics.

Answer (score 2):

Elements of Statistical Learning is a great book. If you read and understand the material, you should be able to discern what algorithms might be better suited for what type of problem. If you'd like a simpler version of that book, try [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) from the same authors. This simpler book focuses more on practical application, providing a comparison of the different methods in the book. It's less comprehensive than the ESL book though.

[This diagram](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/) from SciKit-Learn is a pretty good one for illustrating machine learning possibilities.

But as User777 has already pointed out, usually we narrow down to a few possible procedures and use some sort of cross validation method to test the out-of-sample error rate.

Comment: (+1) That flowchart is going to come in handy.